# How can I disable cascade option?

Tags: css, css-cascade

I have css option for all divs

```css
div {
  background: blue;
}
```

How can I make div with id `myDiv` that will not inherit any css option except `#myDiv`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, that's why they are called Cascading Style Sheets.

The most common solution in such cases would be to override the `background` attribute on `#myDiv` with another rule.

In this specific case, you have the option of using the CSS3 [`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo-class as in `div:not(#myDiv) { background: blue }`, but then you have to account for [browser compatibility](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#css3-selectors) (summary: works on everything except for IE < 9) so I don't think this is a practical option just yet.